# Equivilent first order differential and initial condition?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have another homework question that I'm struggling a bit to understand exactly what I'm asked to do. I understand what an initial condition is, but I'm not quite sure how I specify such a condition. So, here's the problem:

[image]

However, understanding how to specify the initial condition has me stumped. All of the examples in the section specify the condition. As I write this question, it occurs to me that perhaps I must solve my differential equation.

At any rate, this also happens to be an odd numbered problem and so I already know what the authors got, but I don't quite see how to get it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you differentiated both sides, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate the integral?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for writing your comment. He seemed to be asking about the initial condition so I wasn't sure whether I should have included this.

Comment: You were amply taking care of that, and I wondered whether the rest was clear to the OP.

Comment: Your $y$ satisfies the equation $y'(x)=5x-y(x)$, but such an equation has a constant in the solution. The constant is determined by imposing $y(1)=1$, which your $y$ has to satisfy.

Comment: Oops, just noticed I wrote $y(1)=1$. No. $y(1)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we can always specify $y(1)$ in the equation given. In general to specify an initial condition look for values that you can extract immediately from the equation satisfied by $y$.

Comment: Im sorry but I honestly have no clue on what to do

Comment: What happens when you put $x=1$ into $y(x)=2+\int_{1}^{x}(5t-y(t))dt$?

Comment: the integral would just be from 1 to 1 right?

Comment: Yes it would. What would the value of that integral be now?

Comment: would it just be 0?

Comment: Yes it will be $0$. :)

Comment: so is my answer 2? Or are ther more steps?

Comment: Nope that's it. So you have $y(1)=2$ which is an initial condition. To obtain a differential equation you may want to look at the hint proposed by Andre Nicolas.

Comment: Do i substitute x for y? or for t?

Comment: You are substituting $x=1$ into the equation for $y(x)$. $t$ is an integration variable.

Comment: wait what? Im sorry but I don't understand I'm sorry to bother you with my questions

Comment: Not a bother so don't worry. What I meant is that the equation $y(x)=2+\int_{1}^{x}(5t-y(t))dt$ indicates that $y$ is a function of $x$. The function $y(t)$ inside the integral cannot have values substituted for it since $t$ is simply the variable we integrate $(5t-y(t))$ over. For example in $\int_{0}^{1}x dx=\frac{1}{2}$ notice that the integral has an $x$ on the inside but not when you evaluate it.

Comment: okay, so for the integration for this problem i cannot go anything with the t?

Comment: I'm sorry I am so damn stupid man..

Comment: Don't put yourself down. Learning concepts takes time. If by "go anything with the $t$" you mean substituting values for $t$ then yes this is true.

Comment: so how should I differentiate it, I really don't understand, is there any way you could work it out for me, I'm really sorry to be asking for this.

Comment: I think for the purposes of learning I should show you how in general its done and let you try on the actual question. In any case copper.hat has demonstrated how to obtain the derivative. A function of the form $k(x)=\int_{a}^{x}h(t)dt$ where $a$ is a real number has the derivative $k'(x)=h(x)$. This follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. When we try to differentiate $y$ in the equation given notice that the derivative is linear (i.e $(f+g)'=f'+g'$) and that constant functions have $0$ as their derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The function $x \mapsto y(x)$ specified above can only have one value when $x=1$.

Now differentiate $y$ to get $y'(x) = 5x -y(x)$.

**Aside**: If $f(x) = 2+\int_1^x (5 t - y(t)) dt $, then
$f(x+h)-f(x) = \int_x^{x+h} (5 t - y(t)) dt$. Assuming that $y$ is continuous, then for $t \in [x,x+h]$, we have $5t-y(t) \approx 5x-y(x)$, and so $f(x+h)-f(x) \approx (5x-y(x))h$, from which we get $f'(x) = 5x-y(x)$. Now differentiate both sides of the expression $y(x) = 2+\int_1^x (5 t - y(t)) dt $.

To show that this is equivalent to the integral equation, we need to establish that there is a unique solution. This follows from the continuity of
$f$ and the following Lipschitz condition:
Note that the right hand side can be written as $f(x,y)= 5 x -y$, and for fixed $x$, we have $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)| \le |y_1-y_2|$.

**Addendum**: If you have an expression of the form $f(x) = \int_a^x g(t)dt$, where $g$ is continuous, then $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = g(x)$. THis is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that André was referring to.

Comment: So what would be the next step to this?

Comment: Like what do you mean by differentiate y

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry but that just confused me more

Comment: An expression of the form $x \mapsto \int_1^x g(t) dt$ can be differentiated (assuming $g$ is sufficiently smooth). Do you know how to differentiate this expression?

Comment: (I was going to add some more detail, but can see I was headed in the wrong direction at the moment.)

Comment: i have no clue how to

Comment: As Andre Nicolas pointed out you should appeal to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate.

Comment: I have added an aside that hopefully shows some intuition behind the differentiation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am just getting more and more confused.

Comment: I can help you if you can elaborate what is confusing to you.

Comment: Just this problem, I am literally looking at your work and it basically looks like gibberish to me haha

Comment: Well, I am willing to help, but we need some common point of overlap to start. You need to supply that.

Comment: Can you answer the question posed in my first comment? (I am going to sleep shortly; I will help you now if you respond in a timely and reasonable manner.)

Comment: In order to clarify : what does the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says ? PLease answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part

Comment: @copper.hat. Good ! The question was to the OP only !!! Cheers. You make my day. :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: I am afraid that three glasses of wine are pre-empting my ability to help at this moment :-). Will look again in the (my) morning time!